# Unreachable Statement in the constructor that throws exception

Tags: java, try-catch, throw

When I try to run this program I am getting `unreachable statement`  I tried different versions of java and still not working but I am sure that the code is right.

```
       // Lec 25b
public class UsedCar{
   private int VIN;
   private String make;
   private int year;
   private int milage;
   private int price;
   
   public UsedCar(int VIN, String make, int year, int milage, int price) throws Exception{
      if(VIN<1000 || VIN>9999)
         throw new Exception("VIN is not four digits.");
      this.VIN = VIN;
      if(!(make.equalsIgnoreCase("ford") || make.equalsIgnoreCase("honda") || make.equalsIgnoreCase("toyota") || make.equalsIgnoreCase("chrysler") || make.equalsIgnoreCase("other")));
      throw new Exception("Invalid make.");
      this.make = make;
      if(year<=1997 || year>=2017)
         throw new Exception("Year is not betwean 1997 and 2017.");
      this.year = year;
      if(milage<0)
         throw new Exception("Milage is negative.");
      this.milage = milage;
      if(price<0)
         throw new Exception("Price is negative.");
      this.price = price;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args){
      try{
         UsedCar car = new UsedCar(1234,"ford",1999,152,25000);
      }
      catch(Exception exp){
         System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd strongly advise to start using curly braces  - `{ }` and proper indentation in order to stop having problems like these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a ";" at the end of the `if` with the car manufacturer.

```
if(!(make.equalsIgnoreCase("ford") || make.equalsIgnoreCase("honda") || make.equalsIgnoreCase("toyota") || make.equalsIgnoreCase("chrysler") || make.equalsIgnoreCase("other")));
```

Remove this ";" and it will be OK

Answer (score 2):

You end your if-clause with a semicolon. That's why the throw can never be reached.

```
if(!(make.equalsIgnoreCase("ford") ||     
   make.equalsIgnoreCase("honda") ||   
   make.equalsIgnoreCase("toyota") ||    
   make.equalsIgnoreCase("chrysler") ||    
   make.equalsIgnoreCase("other")));
        throw new Exception("Invalid make.");
```

Although Java allows it to not use curly braces when there is only one action after the if-condition, you should really get used to always use them. This prevents you from making such mistakes.

```
if(!(make.equalsIgnoreCase("ford") ||    
    make.equalsIgnoreCase("honda") ||     
    make.equalsIgnoreCase("toyota") ||     
    make.equalsIgnoreCase("chrysler") ||    
    make.equalsIgnoreCase("other"))) {
       throw new Exception("Invalid make.");
}
```